# Deriving CI for the mean: Wolfram Alpha giving different answer for equation and inequality

Tags: confidence-interval, wolfram-alpha

As a simple example, say I'm trying to derive the upper bound of a confidence interval for the mean. That is, I'm trying to solve for $\mu$ in

$$ \frac{\bar{X} - \mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}} < Z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} $$

If I tell Wolfram Alpha [solve (x - mu) / (sigma/sqrt(n)) = z for mu](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve%20%28x%20-%20mu%29%20%2F%20%28sigma%2Fsqrt%28n%29%29%20%3D%20z%20for%20mu), then it gives an answer which is correct.

However, if I tell Wolfram Alpha [solve (x - mu) / (sigma/sqrt(n)) < z for mu](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve%20%28x%20-%20mu%29%20%2F%20%28sigma%2Fsqrt%28n%29%29%20%3C%20z%20for%20mu), then I don't.

Can anyone explain what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A priori, the consequent bound on $\mu$ depends on whether $\sigma > 0$ or $\sigma < 0$. As an artefact of whatever procedure Wolfram Alpha uses, (currently) it also breaks up the cases where $z \ge 0$ and where $z < 0$, even though the answer does not actually depend on this.

From the question title, I'm guessing you know that $\sigma > 0$. If you add this assumption to the query you get the [correct answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve%20%28x%20-%20mu%29%20%2F%20%28sigma%2Fsqrt%28n%29%29%20%3C%20z%20and%20sigma%20%3E%200%20for%20mu), though still split up into cases depending on the sign of $z$.